# Handle #Error from subReport/subform in Access 2010 Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm stuck on this problem on how to deal with #Error when no value exists in a subreport/form in a Report.

The value from the sub is contained in a textbox called '**subFormEmployeeId**', I then check the textbox to see if the value matches the value in another textbox, if yes apply value or apply 0

I have tried:

```
=Nz([frmTotalSales].[Report].[TotalSalesForManagerId],0)
```

This checks is sub has a value if not value is '0', does not work

I have tried:

```
=IIf(Not(IsNumeric([frmTotalSales].[Report].[TotalSalesForManagerId])),"0")
```

Does not work

I have tried:

```
=IIf([subFormEmployeeId]<>[EmployeeID],0,500)
```

and

**`=IIf([subFormEmployeeId]="#Error,0,500)`**

Last 2 are in textbox **Bonus**

I have no idea what else to do.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `IIF(ISERROR([frmTotalSales].[Report].[TotalSalesForManagerId]),0,[frmTotalSales].[Report].[TotalSalesForManagerId])`

Comment: Hi @izzymo tried something similair =IIf(IsError(Nz([frmTotalSales].[Report]![TotalSalesForManagerId],0), 0 , Nz([frmTotalSales].[Report]![TotalSalesForManagerId],0)), also tried yours does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, seems access has a property called 'HasData' which can check if any records are returned, so for anyone else you runs into the same problem you can use:

```
=IIf([SubFormName].[Report].[HasData],[SubFormname].[Report].[NameOfTextBox],0)
```

Cheers